# How can I enable --gc-targets in my Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo, rust-wasm

According to the archival notice in [`wasm-gc`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc),

> The wasm-pack (and wasm-bindgen) project will already run [`--gc-targets`] by default for you, so there's no need to run it again.

How do we specify this in Cargo.toml explictly?

Comment: Question is unclear. What do you want to specify in Cargo explicitly? As responded on your other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135109/does-gc-sections-need-to-be-enabled-with-wasm32-wasi-targets - Cargo doesn't know anything about wasm-gc or how GC-ing is done on Wasm files.

Comment: @RReverser I want to specify in my Cargo toml a directive that instructs rustc or the linker (which 
 ever receives the option) to pass on `--gc-targets`

Comment: There is no `--gc-targets` option. As the description of wasm-gc says, "This is *effectively* --gc-sections for arbitrary wasm executables." - effectively meaning it's not an actual linker option, just a similar postprocessing. And, as it also says, it's unnecessary for Wasm coming from the compiler because it already produces Wasm without unused parts. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Rustc passes arguments with

```
-C, --codegen OPT[=VALUE]
                    Set a codegen option
```

The codegen option you want [link-arg](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/doc/rustc/src/codegen-options/index.md#link-arg) so you'd use it like `-C link-arg=--gc-targets` you can set that up in your Cargo.toml with,

```
[[bin]]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=--gc-targets",
]
```

Alternatively, you can now set this up directly with the new [experimental `extra-link-arg`](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/src/doc/src/reference/unstable.md#extra-link-arg) option in Cargo.