# Does --gc-sections need to be enabled with wasm32-wasi targets?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo

According to the archival notice in [`wasm-gc`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc),

> The Rust compiler now natively supports `--gc-sections` when linking wasm executables, which means wasm executables already have 90% of their garbage removed when coming out of the compiler.

However, when I run `cargo -v build --release --target wasm32-wasi`, I'm not seeing that option,

```
cargo -v build --release --target wasm32-wasi
  Compiling felipe-wasi v0.1.0 (/home/ecarroll/felipe-wasi)
   Running `rustc --crate-name felipe_wasi --edition=2018 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=s -C lto -C metadata=e0e763637e4f02a5 --out-dir /home/ecarroll/felipe-wasi/target/wasm32-wasi/release/deps --target wasm32-wasi -L dependency=/home/ecarroll/felipe-wasi/target/wasm32-wasi/release/deps -L dependency=/home/ecarroll/felipe-wasi/target/release/deps`
  Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.98s
```

Is this option needed on `wasm32-wasi` targets?

---

Follow up question [*"How can I enable --gc-targets in my Cargo.toml?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68135086/124486)

Comment: You don't see it because it's not an option of Cargo that gets passed to rustc but something done by rustc internally.